# How do I run a madlib in python

Tags: python

My madlib will run in the terminal, but when I input things for verbs and adjectives it doesn’t run with them in. Please help.

```
adj = input(“adjective”) 
verb= input(“verb”)
Madlib= “I love to {verb} code, it can become a {adj} skill”
Print(Madlib)
```

It comes out in the terminal of visual studio code correctly, it just doesn’t work after I put stuff in for adjectives and verb

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What happens when you run that script?

Comment: It returns verb (asking for a value) and after I give it one, it asks for a value for adjective. This is in the terminal. I will give them both values, then it won’t run. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Please read what tags you use actually mean. The tag [tag:madlib] has nothing to do with this question. Also note that the code you provided is not proper Python, as it uses the wrong quote characters (and since they copied your code, the same problem appears in some of the answers). Also, unless you have defined it, Python does not know what `Print` is — it only knows `print`.

Comment: My apologies amadan, I just started learning this stuff earlier today so I assumed the tag was fitting becuase it’s literally the name of the question that prompted me to start this line of code

Comment: _I will give them both values, then it won’t run_ What does "it won't run" mean?  It's always better to say what the code **actually does**, instead of what it **doesn't** do.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `f-string` and try this way:

```py
adj = input("adjective: ")
verb= input("verb: ")
Madlib= f"I love to {verb} code, it can become a {adj} skill"
print(Madlib)
```

output:

```
adjective: great
verb: do
I love to do code, it can become a great skill
```

Comment: I have tried with F, but then it only asks me for the verb value, and either way the terminal then puts in the madlib without the verb value

Comment: the input function is being called twice, one for the variable `adj` and 2nd for the variable  `verb`. I don't see any issue as you can see the output, it's the actual output after running the code above

Comment: run the code above, it asks to fill in the value for `adjective`, enter and it asks to fill in the value for the `verb` and enter again to see the output

Answer (score 0):

Begin your string (the text surrounded by ") with f.

So, your code should be

```
adj = input(“adjective”) 
verb= input(“verb”)
Madlib= f“I love to {verb} code, it can become a {adj} skill”
Print(Madlib)
```

It is also good practice to begin variables with a lowercase letter (e.g., Madlib => madlib).

Comment: So I added the F, but the resulting terminal code now only asks me for the verb, and after I put something in for verb it returns me the madlib without the verb or adjective replaced with values

Answer (score 0):

In Python it is not the same thing as we do in Javascript, you either add an "f" before the quotes, or you can simply concatenate strings:

```
madlib = 'I love to ' + verb + ' code, it can become a ' + adj + ' skill'
```

PS: In Python, variables' first letter should be in lowercase.